# onBackPressed Android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I'm delevoping an app with fragment. My problem is when I pressed the back button, from any screen, the app closes. App shows the expected layout but immediatly closes. This is the code of my fragment, who includes a Button.

```
public class LoginFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, OnBackPressed{

    private StatusFragment.StatusListener statusListener;
    public static LoginFragment newInstance() {return new LoginFragment();}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false); //este fragment_profile se muestra

        Button go_login=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button_gologin);
        go_login.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button go_registration=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button_goregistration);
        go_registration.setOnClickListener(this);

        return layout;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //on Back Pressed
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        statusListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_gologin:{
                Model model=(Model)getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                EditText text_log = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
                EditText text_pass = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);

                model.sendLogin(text_log.getText().toString(),text_pass.getText().toString());
                model.isPasswordCorrect();
                break;
            }
```

Then we have the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AccountFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        StatusFragment.StatusListener, ObserverModel {

}

private void showLogin() {
    LoginFragment fragment = (LoginFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);
    if (fragment == null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Открываем статус");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Статус открыт");
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, loginFragment, LOGIN_FRAGMENT).addToBackStack(STATUS);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}



@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
            if (currentFragment instanceof OnBackPressed) {
                ((OnBackPressed) currentFragment).onBackPressed();
            } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
               }
            }
```

Where is the problem? I was reading others post similars but cannot find a solution for it. Thanks

Comment: i think some issue with this line ===>     transaction.replace(R.id.container, loginFragment, LOGIN_FRAGMENT).addToBackStack(STATUS); where did you define "loginFragment" ??? Correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AccountFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        StatusFragment.StatusListener, ObserverModel {

    LoginFragment loginFragment=new LoginFragment()  final static String LOGIN_FRAGMENT="Login";

Comment: add super.onBackPressed to else statement in FragmentActivity and your issue is resolved.

Comment: @AnkushBist exactly in which part? I put it after transaction.commit(); and screen didnt change between fragments, and if I put it in the beginning of showLogicFragment, app falls after the first touch

Comment: thanks, but anyways doesnt work... shows the prevoius fragment and close...

Comment: have got solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity, use this in `onBackPressed` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment != null && fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Add**

In your `showLogin` method:

```
Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: App back but then close ??? App get close after first back press or what ?

Comment: yes, I can go through differents screen, but when I try to back, it shows the desired screen but immediately close

Comment: Do add in your show login method my edit content, remove your.

Answer (score 0):

Put below method in LoginFragment class :

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    return false;
}
```

Put below method in MainActivity class :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean eventConsumed = false;
    List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment instanceof BaseFragment) {
                eventConsumed = eventConsumed
                        || ((BaseFragment) fragment).onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
    if (!eventConsumed) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: app continue falling after pressing "back button" from any fragment on screen

Comment: Try this code. @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        fragment.backButtonWasPressed();
    }

Comment: what do you mean with BaseFragment ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
        if (currentFragment instanceof OnBackPressed) {
            ((OnBackPressed) currentFragment).onBackPressed();
           return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: i think your if condition on MainActivity not working. Check you have properly Use the OnBackPressed interface. eg: OnBackPressed backPressed=new LoginFragment();

Comment: I deleted the "if", but the same result, continue falling after pressing "back button"

Comment: @baldcl No. i am not saying to remove the if condition. Check the onBackPressed has properly has the instance of Particular fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, create one Interface.

```
public interface IOnBackPressed {

    boolean onBackPressed();

}
```

Create on FragmentBackHelper Class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentBackHelper extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed {

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then From your Fragment Class call this method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        if (fragment != null && fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack())

        return super.onBackPressed();
    }
```